# Why is my package not pulling download_url

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I want to shift to using the new [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) for my packages.  I can't figure out what my `download_url` needs to be.  The version is `1.3.5` I've tried various incarnations of the `releases/tag/1.3.5`, `archive/1.3.5`, and `archive/1.3.5#egg=v1.3.5` to no avail.

**My question is that in reading the PEP 438 - I know it's looking for `simple-history-v1.3.5.EXT` but can I force setup.py to use a specific url?**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from simple_history import __version__

base_url = 'https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-simple-history'

setup(name='simple_history',
      version=__version__,
      description='Store Django model history with the ability to revert back to a '
                  'specific change at any time. This includes capturing request.user',
      author='Steven Klass',
      author_email='sklass@pivotalenergysolutions.com',
      url=base_url,
      download_url='{0}/archive/{1}.tar.gz'.format(base_url, __version__),
      license='Apache License (2.0)',
      classifiers=[
          'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
          'Environment :: Web Environment',
          'Framework :: Django',
          'Intended Audience :: Developers',
          'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
          'Operating System :: OS Independent',
          'Programming Language :: Python',
          'Topic :: Software Development',
      ],
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
      package_data={'simple_history': ['static/js/*.js', 'templates/simple_history/*.html']},
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      requires=['django (>=1.2)', ],
)
```

When I do an easy install it's saying its finding it but it always goes back to version 1.1.  Can someone please clue me in on my problem.

```
$ easy_install -vvv simple_history
Searching for simple-history
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/simple_history/
Reading https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-simple-history
Found link: https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-simple-history/archive/master.zip
Found link: https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-simple-history/archive/1.3.5.tar.gz
Found link: https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-simple-history/archive/v1.3.3.tar.gz
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/simple_history/simple_history-1.1.tar.gz#md5=b4c4bb2512904d7826a75f58cc9df651
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/simple_history/simple_history-v1.3.3.tar.gz#md5=1564e23e982553b76a4ed7328fb5b812
Best match: simple-history 1.1
```

Comment: Remove `/releases/` from your URL. Also, you should really consider using [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

Comment: Yeah - I saw that too and have been directly editing it on PyPi.  But still no luck.  It's looking for simple-history-v1.3.3.  Agreed on semantic naming that's next.  I want to get this functioning first..

Comment: Maybe it's the leading `v` in your version number that's throwing it off?

Comment: Nope - Just rolled a new release 1.3.5 and still nothing.  The log file clearly shows it found it - now why wont it use it or how can I force it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide `simple-history-1.3.5.tar.gz` as a download for your release `1.3.5`; in other words `'{0}-{1}{2}'.format(packagename, version, ext)`). See `setuptools.package_index.interpret_distro_name` for reference on how `easy_install` tries to parse the `basename` of the url.

---

*Update:*

In other words, if name your release on GitHub as `<pypi package>-<version>`. This will then allow it to get picked up automatically if you simply change your `download_url` to

```
download_url='{0}/releases'.format(base_url)
# or 
package_name='simple_history' # define it before setup()
download_url='{0}/archive/{1}-{2}'.format(base_url, package_name, __version__)
```

Comment: The right answer is to name your release on GitHub as <pypi package>-<version>.  This will then allow it to get picked up.  If you update your answer I will give you credit - this was what I was suspecting last night.

Comment: The right answer is to name your release on GitHub as <pypi package>-<version>.  This will then allow it to get picked up.  If you update your answer I will give you credit - this was what I was suspecting last night.  Then you need to simply change your download_url to `download_url='{0}/releases'.format(base_url)` or `download_url='{0}/archive/simple_history-{1}.format(base_url, __version__)`